# Why can't I change value without first assigning a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I stumbled upon something strange, I wanted to stop the emission of particle system as follows:

```
laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission.enabled = false;
```

But I get error `CS1612` (cannot modify the return value cause it is not a variable)

But

```
var emissionModule = laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission;
emissionModule.enabled = false;
```

Works, now I searched about this issue but everyone says you can't do it because the return value is returned by value and not by reference, but this can't be true because the code above does indeed change the emission module to `false` in game, it didn't change a local copy in my code it actually changed it on the reference, so my question is why creating a variable first does anything different then just changing it on the same line? it would have worked in JS/Python

**If** I had to do something like

```
var emissionModule = laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission;
emissionModule.enabled = false;
laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission = emissionModule
```

I would have understand this issue better, but I **don't** need to do it like here, I don't need to assign it back again somewhy, it works fine as I showed in the 2nd example so it doesn't make sense, emissionModule seems to be a reference and not a value copy

---

---

**TL;DR version:**
Here is a full example of the code:

```
void changeLasers(bool isActive) {
    foreach (GameObject laser in lasers) {
        var emissionModule = laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission;
        emissionModule.enabled = isActive;
    }
}
```

Which is weird, it **works** but I didn't need to assign it back again so why couldn't I do it in 1 line? seems weird that c# forces me to use another variable here.
This gives the `CS1612` error:

```
void changeLasers(bool isActive) {
    foreach (GameObject laser in lasers) {
        laser.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emission.enabled = isActive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

derHugo's answers the c# issue here (we indeed get a struct by value),
I want to chime in about why we don't need to re-assign the structure back:

---

It wouldn't have worked normally, this is black magic done by the Unity engine behind the scenes (basically applies your struct changes without you needing to re-assign the struct back).

More on this subject here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-particlesystem-emissionmodule-a-struct-and-how-should-we-use-it.821988/
And a bit more detailed:
https://blog.unity.com/technology/particle-system-modules-faq

Comment: This and derHugo's part answer the question :)

Answer (score 2):

> emissionModule seems to be a reference and not a value copy

Well, it is not ;)

[`EmissionModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule.html) is a **struct** and therefore the [`ParticleSystem.emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html) property returns a copy by value!

Since Unity is actually mainly a C++ engine and the c# is just a layer on top of it most of the components properties are actually just wrappers for getters and setters into the underlying C++ part where they are actually implemented. (See [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/d3aaa4d6a73002d216e8fdfda689a55b7c832442/Modules/ParticleSystem/ScriptBindings/ParticleSystemModules.bindings.cs#L78))

=> Most of the properties in Unity behave exactly like that and you always need to use the getter, store them, modify them and assign them back again.

In this case it is very possible that internally that struct still aslso holds a reference to the system which allows the `enabled` property to directly affect the underlying system.

Still since c# is how it is you can not directly modify the value of the returned struct.

Comment: I may not understand structs then, but if it is a copy by value why doing emissionModule.enabled = false, affects the laser's ParticleSystem.emission (if I understand correctly structs copied by value so changing it shouldn't have made any changes in game if I didn't re-apply it back e.g 3rd example, but 2nd example worked)

Comment: "modify them and assign them back again." this is what confuses me, it worked without assigning it back again

Comment: It is possible that internally the struct has a reference to the system and can update it accordingly.. still c# simply doesn't allow to directly modify the value of the struct

Comment: yea you are right this question couldn't be answered with just C# knowledge, it is the Unity engine doing black magic behind the scenes... we could have never guessed it :D